# Predict probabilities from Firth logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic

I'm using the `logistf` package in R to perform Firth logistic regression on an unbalanced dataset. I have a logistf object:

```
fit = logistf(a~b)
```

Is there a `predict()` function like on that's used in the `lm` class to predict probabilities for future data points? Or do I have to manually input the estimated parameters from the Firth regression.

Comment: If you type ?logistf you will see
**predict 
a vector with the predicted probability of each observation.**
is that what you want?

Comment: thanks, but no i was looking for a function to predict the probabilities for future data points, not the fitted data points

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably compute any predictions you want with little algebra. Let consider the example dataset,

```
data(sex2)
fm <- case ~ age+oc+vic+vicl+vis+dia
fit <- logistf(fm, data=sex2)
```

A design matrix is the only missing piece to compute predicted probabilities once we get the regression coefficients, given by

```
betas <- coef(fit)
```

So, let's try to get prediction for the observed data, first:

```
X <- model.matrix(fm, data=sex2)       # add a column of 1's to sex2[,-1]
pi.obs <- 1 / (1 + exp(-X %*% betas))  # in case there's an offset, δ, it 
                                       # should be subtracted as exp(-Xβ - δ)
```

We can check that we get the correct result

```
> pi.obs[1:5]
[1] 0.3389307 0.9159945 0.9159945 0.9159945 0.9159945
> fit$predict[1:5]
[1] 0.3389307 0.9159945 0.9159945 0.9159945 0.9159945
```

Now, you can put in the above design matrix, `X`, values you are interested in. For example, with all covariates set to one

```
new.x <- c(1, rep(1, 6))
1 / (1 + exp(-new.x %*% betas))
```

we get an individual probability of 0.804, while when all covariates are set to 0 (`new.x <- c(1, rep(0, 6))`), the estimated probability is 0.530.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative approach is the **brglm** package. For example, using the same data/model as @chl's Answer

```
data(sex2)
fm <- case ~ age + oc + vic + vicl + vis + dia
fit <- brglm(fm, data = sex2)

predict(fit, newdata = sex2[1:5, ], type = "response")
```

That yields the

```
> predict(fit, newdata = sex2[1:5, ], type = "response")
        1         2         3         4         5 
0.3389307 0.9159945 0.9159945 0.9159945 0.9159945
```

Note that in the `brglm()` case, because of the way the function works, what you see above is simply the result of the standard `predict.glm()` function/method in R.

Comment: Do you know of papers that utilise this package in their analysis? I would like to know how to interpret the results.